# CORS: policy differs if accessing URL from browser or from within script

Tags: javascript, http, get, cors

If I access server right through browser's address field, server successfully responds.
But when I try accessing it from my **send.js** script:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open( 'GET', "myserver.com", true );
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8;");
request.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    document.write( "received response: " + request.response );
};
document.write( "sending request ..." );
request.send( 'login=billy&password=sunshines' );
```

accessing it through **index.html** over Mongoose local web server with browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Server send script TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="send.js"></script>
</body>
```

It fails with error: **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://192.168.0.101:8080' is therefore not allowed access.**

Why CORS policy differs when I access page directly through browser's address field from when I access through locally hosted script? Am I missing some fields to specify for request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you access the script directly by using the address bar there is no cross origin resource sharing taking place.  Your browser navigated to `myserver.com` so any request to `myserver.com` is same-origin.

When your browser location is `http://192.168.0.101:8080`, a request to `myserver.com` is Cross-Origin because your browser location differs from the location to which you're making http requests.

You'll have to enable CORS on your backend or use JSONP.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "navigated to" here ? The request origin is still the browser and it's from 192.168.0.101 from ? Am I missing something @sheepdog